# useExternalPagination and rowselection in angular UIGrid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-select

I'm working on AngularJS UI Grid and when I use useExternalPagination,useExternalSorting attributes are true, Rowselection is not working.
 Below is my grid properties

```
    $scope.gridOption = {
        'excessRows': 20, 
        enableSorting: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        enablePaginationControls: false,
        paginationPageSizes: [10,20],
        paginationPageSize: 10,
        rowHeight: 160, 
        minRowsToShow: 6,
        useExternalPagination: true,
        useExternalSorting: true,
        rowTemplate: 'temp.html'
    };
```

my external pagination in onRegisterApi,

```
$scope.gridOption.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
$scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function(newPage, pageSize) {
                    pagination.pageNumber = newPage;
                    pagination.pageSize = pageSize;
                    setData();
    });
};

   function setData() {
    http.get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOption.totalItems = data.total;
    $scope.gridOption.data =  data.grid;
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOption.data[0]);
            },1000);
        }
```

As you see above,I'm selecting first data in the grid.
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOption.data[0]); but this is not selecting the first row.

if I remove the attributes useExternalPagination, useExternalSorting selectRow is selecting the specified Row..I need to use externalpagination and rowselection options. Am I missing anything in the code?

Any helping hands....

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: It will be good, if you can provide a plunker link replicating the issue.

Comment: Hi Sai.. Thanks for reply. I tried and I'm unsuccessful to make plunker for my code. I could not see any Plunker or samples to use external pagination with row selection. If you found any plunker link or samples, it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example pluncker with useExternalPagination, useExternalSorting and enableRowSelection functionalities.

http://plnkr.co/edit/I67c3xTkBeXq5OnMkIad?p=preview

Checklist: 1) Make sure you are using the latest version of the ui-grid(3.0.7).
           2) Check whether you have added all the required dependencies.

HTML:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
    paginationPageSize: 25,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true
 };
```

Comment: HI Sai.. This is great.. My issue is, if you are selecting first row in first page, then navigate to second page. Now back to first page the selected row is not highlighted or selection is gone. I have stored all selection in one scope variable and try to select the particular row by Quote:     $timeout(function() {
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0],true);
      });  unQuote. i have all the selected rows in my scope variable, what i need i have to  highlight the selected rows during navigation

Comment: Here are some workarounds mentioned https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3224  I am not sure whether they will help you.